# Problem with "nuget restore" with some lib's in build azure Pipeline

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core-3.1

I am using netcoreapp3.1 and everything works with the command dotnet restore and dotnet build, but in the build pipeline, the command used is nuget restore, and this causes the following errors:

```
 Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch 3.1.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch 3.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the wrong Agent Specification, the correct would be windows-2019 I was using windows-2017

Answer (score 5):

In my scenario, I had to install NuGet 5.4.0 (released with .NET Core 3.1) to fix this

If using YAML templates in Azure DevOps you can add this task:

```yaml
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.4.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

this solved

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.x'
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60726554/109941